# How to access index of outer for loop of nested iterrow in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I am iterating through a datafile in the outermost loop and a series in the inner loop. I am using iterrows() and items() to iterate through both data structures respectively. From the pandas documentation, it seems that the 'index' name cannot be a variable name I declare.

So, when I am inside the items() loop, the 'index' I access is the index from the series, but I want the index from the datafile.

Ultimately, I want to be able to drop a specific row while I am iterating, but the fact that I have a nested loop seems to complicate things.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

I tried to just set a boolean instead of dropping the row right away and then drop the row when I am outside the items loop, but that doesn't work.

```
for index, row in ldf.iterrows():
   for index, value in comp.items():
        if row['Type'] == index:
            if row['Score'] < value:
                 ldf.drop(index,inplace=True)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the index name cannot be a variable name you declare"?

Comment: Use a different name in the outer loop - `for rowindex, row ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right, you just need to use different variable names for the two loop variables:

```
for df_index, row in ldf.iterrows():
   for comp_index, value in comp.items():
        if row['Type'] == comp_index:
            if row['Score'] < value:
                 ldf.drop(df_index, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Oh, that was it. My mistake, I thought it failed before when I tried that. Thank you!